# How to check in JSTL whether object is String or Collection?

Tags: java, jstl

I'm using JSTL and want to check whether an object is a String or a Collection.

fn:length returns results on both types (stringsize or number of elements in the collection).

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(item)>1}">
   <c:out value="${fn:length(item)} " />
</c:if>
```

How can I determine which one I've got?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could look at the class name. For example:

```
<c:if test="${item.class.simpleName == 'String'}">
   <!-- it's a String! -->
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 9):

item.class lead to errors when using with tomcat 7.
For me this works (although it's dirtier):

```
${item.link.getClass().simpleName == 'String'}
```

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me because of the newer version of Tomcat, but this did.  Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't really work because what comes back for `getClass().simpleName` is **not** a String but `java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry`.

Comment: @gene: OP primarily wanted to check whether item is a String or something else. It works perfectly fine for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to distinguish whether something is a Collection or not, you can use iteration to find out if it's a Collection, and set a var. This worked for me:

```
<c:set var="collection" value="false" />
<c:forEach var="item" items="${yourObjectWhichMayBeCollection}" varStatus="row">
    <c:if test="${row.index > 0}">
       <c:set var="collection" value="true" />
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
<!--Now you can examine ${collection} & decide e.g. Collection vs. String -->
```